# Does the sequence satisfy WLLN?

Tags: self-study, law-of-large-numbers

Could you help me prove that the following sequence of independent random variables satisfy Weak Law of Large Numbers?

$$P(X_n = n - \sqrt{3}) = P(X_n=-n- \sqrt{3}) = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: Please also *read* the `self-study` [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and change your question to address the points raised there.

Comment: The WLLN, [as usually stated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), concerns a sequence of independent *and identically distributed* variables. Because these obviously do not have identical distributions, either there is nothing more to say--the WLLN does not apply--or else you are referring to some generalization of the WLLN. If so, what does that generalization state?

Comment: Hint: What is the expected value of $X_n$? Is this information enough, or not, to conclude on whether the WLLN holds?

Comment: Will only calculating the expectation and showing that it converges to a constant be enough? Could you do it and post it as an answer please @AlecosPapadopoulos? Really stuck on the concept there.

Answer (score 5):

*(Upadte May 6 2014: The answer now actually addresses the question. I left the original answer as a possibly interesting variant).*

I post this answer because I thought of a simple (or just naive?) way to analyze the problem at hand, in the hope of generating some corrective comments.

The sequence $\{X_n\}$ is not a subject matter of the Weak Law of Large Numbers (and it doesn't converge anyway), so I guess what the OP means is to examine the case for the average sum $\frac 1n S_n \equiv \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

We are looking at  independent non-identical dichotomous random variables. The constant term $-\sqrt 3$ is just a distraction. So we center the r.v.'s and we examine

$$X_i =\cases{i\qquad &p=1/2\\ \\ -i\qquad &p=1/2} \;\;\;\;i=1,...,n$$

We easily calculate that $E[X_i] = 0$, free of $i$, while $\operatorname {Var}(X_i) = i^2$. So these random variables have common and finite expected value, but different variance which increases as the index increases. We also have that $E[\frac 1nS_n] = 0$, while $\operatorname {Var}(\frac 1nS_n) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = (n+1)(2n+1)/(6n)$ (thanks whuber), which diverges as the index increases. So, with non-identical r.v.'s, which have larger and larger variance to infinity, and a sequence whose additional elements have support that tends to $\{\pm \infty\}$, we should be careful regarding convergence.

An approach to the matter is as follows: We denote $A_n$ the subject of indices $i$ for which $X_i = i$. Then we can write $X_i$ using indicator functions as

$$X_i = i\cdot \mathbf 1\{i\in A_n\} -i\cdot (1-\mathbf 1\{i\in A_n\}) = i\cdot\big(2\cdot \mathbf 1\{i\in A_n\}-1\big)$$

We also can write

$$\frac 1{n+1}S_{n+1} = \frac 1{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}X_i = \frac n{n+1}\left(\frac 1{n}S_n\right) + \frac 1{n+1}X_{n+1}$$

$$= \frac n{n+1}\left(\frac 1{n}S_n\right) + \frac 1{n+1}(n+1)\cdot\big(2\cdot \mathbf 1\{i\in A_n\}-1\big) \\
= \frac n{n+1}\left(\frac 1{n}S_n\right) + 2\cdot \mathbf 1\{n+1\in A_n\}-1$$

if we consider the probability limits of the two sides of this equation we have

$$\operatorname{plim}\left(\frac 1{n+1}S_{n+1}\right) = \operatorname{plim}\left(\frac n{n+1}\right) \cdot \operatorname{plim}\left(\frac 1{n}S_{n}\right) + \operatorname{plim}\left(2\cdot \mathbf 1\{n+1\in A_n\}\right)-1$$

$$\Rightarrow \operatorname{plim}\left(\frac 1{n+1}S_{n+1}\right) = \operatorname{plim}\left(\frac 1{n}S_{n}\right)+ 2\operatorname{plim}\left(\mathbf 1\{n+1\in A_n\}\right)-1$$

But the indicator function does not converge in probability -it always takes the values $0$ or $1$ irrespective of the value of the index. So we arrive at

$$\Rightarrow \operatorname{plim}\left(\frac 1{n+1}S_{n+1}\right) = \operatorname{plim}\left(\frac 1{n}S_{n}\right) \pm 1$$

which I believe tells us that $\frac 1{n}S_{n}$ does not converge in probability. This result essentially comes from the fact that each additional element of the sum equals in absolute value the index divisor *with certainty*, and so it cancels it out.

> **A VARIANT**

Consider the following variant

$$X_i =\cases{n\qquad &p=1/2\\ \\ -n\qquad &p=1/2} \;\;\;\;i=1,...,n$$

Here, the r.v's comprising the sum are identically distributed, and they are different for each different index. The expected value remains $0$ as before, but the variance now is $\operatorname {Var}(\frac 1nS_n) = n$.

Since the r.v.'s are dichotomous, we can set $n_a$ to be the number of r.v.'s obtaining the value $n$ and $n_b$ the number of r.v.'s obtaining the value $-n$, $n_a+n_b=n$. Then we can write

$$\frac 1nS_n = \frac 1n \big[n_a\cdot n-n_b\cdot n)\big] = n_a-n_b$$

To check whether the Weak Law of Large Numbers holds, we need to examine whether
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathrm{Pr}\left(\left|\frac 1n S_n \right|>\varepsilon\right)=?\;\;0,\qquad \forall \varepsilon >0$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathrm{Pr}\left(\left|n_a-n_b \right|>\varepsilon\right)=?\;\;0,\qquad \forall \varepsilon >0$$

We note that $n_a$ and $n_b$ are integers. So their difference will be an integer too. The condition for the WLLN is that the above probability goes to zero $\forall \varepsilon >0$ and so also  $\forall \;0<\varepsilon <1$. Since the term $|n_a-n_b|$ is an integer assuming values $\{0,1,...\}$, then the condition for the WLLN can only be fully satisfied if 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathrm{Pr}\left(\left| n_a-n_b \right|=0\right)=1 
\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathrm{Pr}\left(n_a=n_b \right)=1 $$
to cover the case $ \;0<\varepsilon <1$.

But although $\operatorname{plim}(n_b/n)= \operatorname{plim}(n_a/n) =1/2$, this is not the same as saying that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathrm{Pr}\left(n_a=n_b \right)=1$. The event $\{n_a=n_b\}$ will not hold with probability $1$, even at the limit. So neither here $\frac 1nS_n$ appears to converge in probability to its expected value.

Comment: (+1: Interesting exposition.) It seems to me that $\text{Var}(\frac{1}{n}S_n)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = (n+1)(2n+1)/(6n)\approx n/3$. Regardless, could you furnish a statement of the version of the WLLN you are using here?

Comment: @whuber Oops, correct about the variance (I treated $n$ as a constant). As for the version of WLLN, well, actually I didn't try to use any, this was an exploratory exposition. We have non-identical r.v.'s with finite but asymptotically diverging variance, and I don't recall any such WLLN version (I am not saying that it doesn't exist). So I analyzed the problem and then tried to check directly the probability limit and whether the average sum converges in probability to the common expected value.

Comment: @whuber I apologize -my exposition is for a _different_ set of random variables. I am correcting.